# Change the order of StructFileds for an ArrayType column in spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with a column called StudentDetails

dataType: `ArrayType(StructType(StructField(email,StringType,true), StructField(id,LongType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true)),true)`

In the later steps using `to_json` method, I am converting to an Array of JSON which results in

```
[{"email":"abc@xyz.com","id":11,"name":"abc"}]
```

how do I change it to type:
`ArrayType(StructType(StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(id,LongType,true), StructField(email,StringType,true)),true)` ?

so that the order of fields change to (name and email positions should swap)

```
[{"name":"abc","id":11,"email":"abc@xyz.com"}]
```

I tried below snippets:

snippet 1:

```
 val orderedColumn = col("StudentDetails").cast(
                  "array<struct<name:String, type_id:bigint, email:String>>")              
    df.withColumn("StudentDetails", to_json(orderedColumn))
```

snippet 2:

```
val orderedColumn = col("StudentDetails").cast(ArrayType(
                  StructType(Array(
                      StructField("name", StringType, true),
                      StructField("id", LongType, true),
                      StructField("email", StringType, true))), true)
                ).as("StudentDetails")            
    df.withColumn("StudentDetails", to_json(orderedColumn))
```

With the above 2 snippets, my output is

```
[{"name":"abc@xyz.com","id":11,"email":"abc"}]
```

Here only column name changes but not the value.

I cannot change the way we create the spark dataframe df, the only option is to transform the column using some way. Using spark 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on pasha701's answer and Chris's comment, I modified the code

df.withColumn("StudentDetails",
to_json(expr("transform(StudentDetails, col -> named_struct('name', col.name, 'id', col.id, 'email', col.email) )")))

this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Function `transform` can be used:

```
    //    case class Student(email: String, id: Long, name: String)
val df = Seq(
  Array(Student("abc@xyz.com", 11, "abc"))
).toDF("StudentDetails")

val result = df.withColumn("StudentDetails",
  transform($"StudentDetails",
    sd => struct(sd.getField("name"), sd.getField("id"), sd.getField("email")))
)
```

Result:

```
+------------------------+
|StudentDetails          |
+------------------------+
|[{abc, 11, abc@xyz.com}]|
+------------------------+
```

Result schema:

```
root
 |-- StudentDetails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Sry, updated my qsn, I am using an older version: spark 2.4, I don't see transform available there.

Comment: sql transform is available on 2.4 https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.8/api/sql/#transform so you can use selectExpr("transform...") and follow the approach from pasha.  The functions.transform wasn't introduced until 3